# java.util.concurrent.Phaser callback after phase termination

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, phaser

I investigate `Phaser` from `java.util.concurrent` package and I wrote code sample:

```
public class ThreadsApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);
        new Thread(new PhaseThread(phaser, "PhaseThread 1")).start();
        new Thread(new PhaseThread(phaser, "PhaseThread 2")).start();

        // ждем завершения фазы 0
        int phase = phaser.getPhase();
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
        System.out.println("phase " + phase + " finished");
        // ждем завершения фазы 1
        phase = phaser.getPhase();
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
        System.out.println("phase " + phase + " finished");

        // ждем завершения фазы 2
        phase = phaser.getPhase();
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
        System.out.println("phase " + phase + " finished");

        phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
    }
}

class PhaseThread implements Runnable {

    Phaser phaser;
    String name;

    PhaseThread(Phaser p, String n) {

        this.phaser = p;
        this.name = n;
        phaser.register();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(name + " start execute phase " + phaser.getPhase());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // сообщаем, что первая фаза достигнута

            System.out.println(name + " start execute phase " + phaser.getPhase());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // сообщаем, что вторая фаза достигнута

            System.out.println(name + " start execute phase " + phaser.getPhase());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            phaser.arriveAndDeregister(); // сообщаем о завершении фаз и удаляем с регистрации объекты

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
PhaseThread 2 start execute phase 0
PhaseThread 1 start execute phase 0
PhaseThread 2 start execute phase 1
phase 0 finished
PhaseThread 1 start execute phase 1
phase 1 finished
PhaseThread 1 start execute phase 2
PhaseThread 2 start execute phase 2
phase 2 finished
```

Output a bit distinct from desired by me:

I want :

```
PhaseThread 2 start execute phase 0
PhaseThread 1 start execute phase 0
phase 0 finished
PhaseThread 2 start execute phase 1
PhaseThread 1 start execute phase 1
phase 1 finished
PhaseThread 1 start execute phase 2
PhaseThread 2 start execute phase 2
phase 2 finished
```

Thus I want that `phase X finished` will be printed **strict after** both  `PhaseThread # start execute phase X` and strict before `PhaseThread # start execute phase X+1`

I understand why my code works inproper but I don't know how to achieve desired behaviour. I think that it is possible because everywhere written that `Phaser` cover `CyclicBarrier` functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the Java Doc for [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) shows an overridle method called `onAdvance` which can be used to Print the `phase X finished` when the phase is actually finished. Just modify the code as below.

```
public class ThreadsApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1) {
            protected boolean onAdvance(int phase, int parties) { 
                System.out.println("phase " + phase + " finished");
                return false; 
            }
        };
        new Thread(new PhaseThread(phaser, "PhaseThread 1")).start();
        new Thread(new PhaseThread(phaser, "PhaseThread 2")).start();

        // ждем завершения фазы 0
        int phase = phaser.getPhase();
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();

        // ждем завершения фазы 1
        phase = phaser.getPhase();
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();


        // ждем завершения фазы 2
        phase = phaser.getPhase();
        phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
    }
}

class PhaseThread implements Runnable {

    Phaser phaser;
    String name;

    PhaseThread(Phaser p, String n) {

        this.phaser = p;
        this.name = n;
        phaser.register();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(name + " start execute phase " + phaser.getPhase());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // сообщаем, что первая фаза достигнута

            System.out.println(name + " start execute phase " + phaser.getPhase());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // сообщаем, что вторая фаза достигнута

            System.out.println(name + " start execute phase " + phaser.getPhase());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            phaser.arriveAndDeregister(); // сообщаем о завершении фаз и удаляем с регистрации объекты

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know of `onAdvance` nice catch, . The order that the threads print `start execute phase` is of course not 100% ensured.